# How to ask the same question back

Tags: english-to-german

Is there a short way of asking someone the same question they asked you? For example in English we asked "did you do ..." and you can respond with "yes did you?" Can you do the same thing in german? If you are asking a question perfekt does it change to hast du or bist du

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can, and basically in the very same manner:

> Hast Du den Film schon gesehen?
>
> - Ja. Und Du?

> Hast Du schon mal am Neujahrsschwimmen teilgenommen?
>
> - Ne, (das ist mir zu kalt.) Hast Du?

> Die Ausdauer von Marathonläufern kann ich nur bewundern. Du läufst doch auch. Bist Du schon mal Marathon gelaufen?
>
> - Ja, ein paar wenige Male. Ziemlich anstrengend, aber hinterher geil. Bist Du?

Also in the latter two cases I likely would rather use "Und Du?" instead of the "Hast Du?" or "Bist Du?" respectively which pick up the verb of the asked sentence - but either the proper form of the "haben"/"sein" is fine or you can preceed it with and "und" or replace it by an "und": Und (bist/hast) Du?. Of course if you konjugate the verb according the the subject (Du/ihr/wir/sie/Sie/er/es).

Other similarly used versions are "Du auch?" or "Und selbst?" (thx Janka & Jonathan Scholback).

If you consider the positive answer very unlikely and you would want to express your incredulity that it is even a question, one could use "Du etwa?". One can use "Du etwa nicht?" if anything but an outright affirmation will be a big surprise. Even the whole conversation can be quite abriged in the right context without being impolite (e.g. here between colleagues or friends - thx YPOC for the example):

> Schon gegessen?
>
> - Ne, du?"

Comment: Another option is *Du auch?*

Comment: Yet another option, a little more sloppy: _Und selbst?_

Comment: It can be even shorter if it's very clear what the intention is: "Schon gegessen?" "Ne, du?"